# Style the Angular Material Slider so that it is thicker / taller

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm having problems finding the magic sauce here..  It doesn't look like the API supports it, so I guess I'm looking for some CSS to make the slider bigger.

[image]

I am getting the one on the left, but I would like to style it like the one on the right?  Any CSS tricks or has anyone done this before.

Specifically the height of the 'bar'.
there are a million things set to height: 2px. i tried upping all of them but nothing changed.. i guess maybe it's a border or something else?

Thanks in advance!

StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/kkmmddyaegp?file=app%2Fslider-overview-example.css
(Thanks @Andriy)

Comment: Which bit are you struggling with? Are you able to create a Stackblitz with what you've tried? A few CSS classes should do the trick I think

Comment: Here is a demo to play with: https://stackblitz.com/angular/kkmmddyaegp?file=app%2Fslider-overview-example.css

Comment: there are a million things set to height: 2px.  i tried upping all of them but nothing changed..  i guess maybe it's a border or something else..

Comment: @user184994 specifically the height of the bar

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try to add this CSS to global style:

```
.mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-wrapper {
  top: 18px;
}
.mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-track-wrapper {
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 10px
}
.mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-track-background,
.mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-track-fill {
  height: 100%;
}
.mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-track-fill {
  background-color: blue;
}
.mat-accent .mat-slider-thumb {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 2px gray;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: -20px;
}
.mat-slider-min-value:not(.mat-slider-thumb-label-showing) .mat-slider-thumb {
  background-color: white;
}
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cbtsy3?file=styles.css)

if you need to have these styles in any component's CSS file with default [encapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation), just add `::ng-deep` before each CSS rule (but be aware of its long going [deprecation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep), so check it with each new versions of Angular):

```
::ng-deep .mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-wrapper {
  top: 18px;
}
::ng-deep .mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-track-wrapper {
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 10px
}
...
```

if using SASS, just wrap your code with ::`ng-deep`

```
::ng-deep {
  .mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-wrapper {
    top: 18px;
  }
  .mat-slider.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-track-wrapper {
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 10px
  }
  ...
}
```

Please note, that this way your CSS will affect global CSS scope.

Comment: #andriy in mac safari browser border radius not working and color not display while slider change, any idea please

Comment: hi @dhana, I checked it in MAC Safari and it looks exactly the same as in Chrome or Firefox. I could see not rounded borders while stackblitz app was loading, but once loaded, it looks correctly. I tested it on macOS Mojave 10.14, Safari 2.0 (14606.1.36.1.9). If you still have issues, try to test it in plain HTML (not stackblitz) and check on which macOS and Safari versions you observe it.

Comment: How to do this but in the css of the component?

Answer (score 8):

The most direct solution is probably to use `transform`. Something like:

```
my-slider {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

See MDN for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Answer (score 3):

Just overwrite mat css with this

```
.mat-slider-track-fill,
.mat-slider-wrapper,
.mat-slider-track-wrapper,
.mat-slider-track-background {
    height: 5px !important;
}
```

Comment: simple and effective

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
.mat-slider-thumb {
  background-color: #3f51b5 !important;
  border: none !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #000;
  outline: 5px solid #fff;
}

.mat-slider-track-fill {
  background-color: #3f51b5 !important;
}

.mat-slider-track-fill,
.mat-slider-wrapper,
.mat-slider-track-wrapper,
.mat-slider-track-background {
  height: 10px !important;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Demo: [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cayvqr?file=styles.css)

Answer (score 3):

with the latest [migration](https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration) to material web components you can customize the respective [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) like that:

```css
:root {
    --mdc-slider-inactive-track-height: 2px;
    --mdc-slider-active-track-height: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this works for me

```
:root {
    --slider-height: 28px;
}
.mdc-slider .mdc-slider__tick-marks {
    height: var(--slider-height);
}

.mdc-slider .mdc-slider__track--inactive,
.mdc-slider .mdc-slider__track {
    height: calc(var(--slider-height) - 2px);
}

.mdc-slider .mdc-slider__track--active {
    height: var(--slider-height);
}

.mdc-slider .mdc-slider__track--active_fill {
    height: var(--slider-height);
    border-top-width: var(--slider-height);
}

.mdc-slider .mdc-slider__thumb-knob {
    height: calc(var(--slider-height) + 9px);
    width: calc(var(--slider-height) + 9px);
}
```